# error using classes with python

Tags: python

I've been creating a small tile based engine with pygame and recently when I added camera python suddenly dosen't like a class that I haven't tuched(as far as I remember) except for the last line in the last method, but now I'm getting problem using the class:

http://i1344.photobucket.com/albums/p642/tobbeman/spelmotorFel1_zps689775f2.jpg
http://i1344.photobucket.com/albums/p642/tobbeman/spelmotorFel2_zps5deb0c0d.jpg

Any insight would be appreciated!
-Tobbe

*EDIT

```
from player import *
from levelclass import *
```

This is how I've been imported

```
self.player = Player()
self.level = Level()
```

This is how I'm trying to use the classes

```
self.level = Level()
NameError: global name 'Level' is not defined
```

And this is the error I'm getting, my question is, why?
The classes looks pretty much the same except for levelclass in which i'm importing other classes aswell, the classes looks like this:

```
from tileclass import *
from cameraclass import *


class Level:
    def __init__(self):
```

and

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
```

Anyone know why it won't import?

Comment: please change screenshots to code snippets, which can be reproduced and read easily

Comment: It is not a question.

Comment: Unless you zoom the browser in REALLY far, it is almost impossible to read the code in the screenshots.  Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

`Level` isn't defined in your engine.py. Add to engine.py

```
from .levelclass import Level
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work by removing some importes, classes were importing classes they didn't need to use, my quess is that it went around in a circle; camera imports engine->engine imports camera->camera imports engine and so on, thanks for the time used tried to help me tho:)